# Problem with Arc

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I need to construct an arc depending on a variable.  Some lines of the code work some do not.
Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\def\BLS{\baselineskip}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% works
\draw[->] (0,0) arc (-90:90:.5*\BLS) ;

% works
\draw[->] (0,0) arc (-90:90:\BLS{} and 2cm) ;

% don't work
\draw[->] (0,0) arc (-90:90:.5*\BLS{} and 2cm) ;

% don't work
\draw[->] (0,0) arc (-90:90:.5*\BLS and \BLS) ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
\draw[->] (0,0) arc (-90:90:{.5*\BLS} and 2cm);   
\draw[->] (0,0) arc (-90:90:{.5*\BLS} and \BLS);
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use:

```
\draw[->] (0,0) arc (-90:90:\BLS{}/2 and 2cm) ;
\draw[->] (0,0) arc (-90:90:\BLS/2 and \BLS) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another way:

```
\draw[->] (0,0) arc (-90:90:\dimexpr.5\BLS\relax\space and 2cm) ;
```

Comment: The extra keystrokes are not deliberately added.